# Getting sha of file on GitHub not working

Tags: javascript, github, octokit-js

When I try to get the sha of a certain file on GitHub the *undefined* value is returned. I was using the same method several days ago and everything was ok. How to get sha?

```js
let text = '';
import {Octokit} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/octokit";
import token from "./config.js";
const token_string = token.token_string;
export const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: token_string,
});
const put_ob_01 = {
    owner: "na-czczo", repo: "r", file_path: "f.json"
};
const {data: {sha}} = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{file_path}', put_ob_01);
text = sha;
console.log(`%c${text}`, 'color: brown')
```

### edit

I changed the code to get the whole result. Then you can see the result. SHA is not present over there.

```js
import {Octokit} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/octokit";
import token from "./config.js";

const token_string = token.token_string;
export const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: token_string,
});
const put_ob_01 = {
    owner: "na-czczo", repo: "r", file_path: "f.json"
};
const result = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{file_path}', put_ob_01);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, "\n"))
```

> {
>
> "status": 200,
>
> "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/na-czczo/r/contents/f.json",
>
> "headers": {
>
> "cache-control": "private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60",
>
> "content-length": "185",
>
> "content-type": "application/vnd.github.v3.raw; charset=utf-8",
>
> "etag": ""078b905d0bde1d7dc38efe61a42a4b47def7ac4d"",
>
> "last-modified": "Wed, 01 Mar 2023 19:31:58 GMT",
>
> "x-accepted-oauth-scopes": "",
>
> "x-github-media-type": "github.v3; param=raw",
>
> "x-github-request-id": "4E4A:304B:9608AE2:98A4C52:63FFD3F0",
>
> "x-oauth-scopes": "repo",
>
> "x-ratelimit-limit": "5000",
>
> "x-ratelimit-remaining": "4997",
>
> "x-ratelimit-reset": "1677711871",
>
> "x-ratelimit-resource": "core",
>
> "x-ratelimit-used": "3"
>
> },
>
> "data": "{\n  "array": [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3\n  ],\n
> "boolean": true,\n  "color": "gold",\n  "null": null,\n
> "number": 123,\n  "object": {\n    "a": "b",\n    "c":
> "d"\n  },\n  "string": "Hello World"\n}\n" }

Comment: why is that `let text` above your import statements?

Comment: Try using `const result = await octokit.request(...)` and log the entire result to see what you're getting.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I use a special template for console.log and it has text variable as you can see in the code. I copy and paste the template and I do not change the variable. I can change it if you want.

Comment: @trzczy what Mike is saying is that your `import` statements should be above any other code

Comment: @Barmar I edited the question accordingly to your suggestion

Comment: That seems to have retrieved the contents of your file which isn't what it's supposed to do. If I use the REST API directly via curl, I get the expected metadata about the file instead... `curl -v "https://api.github.com/repos/na-czczo/r/contents/f.json"`

Comment: I compared the result of JS to curl and it is the SHA in JS api actually but in the key "etag". So it resolved the problem. But I still find it strange because several days ago the key was sha in JS api

Comment: `etag` comes from the HTTP header, `sha` is in the github API's JSON. It's not clear how Octokit is processing the response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the resolution. We must add the branch.

```js
import {Octokit} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/octokit";
import token from "./config.js";

const token_string = token.token_string;
export const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: token_string,
});
const put_ob_01 = {
    owner: "na-czczo", repo: "r", file_path: "f.json", branch: "main"
};
const result = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{file_path}', put_ob_01);
console.log('The sha is', result.data.sha);
```

> The sha is 078b905d0bde1d7dc38efe61a42a4b47def7ac4d